# Output two times in same line

Tags: powershell, output

I am trying to output two things on the same line rather than a new line and I am unsure how to do this or if it's even possible.

```
"Tag # Entered"; "-------------"; echo $tag1;

$OSInfo | Format-Table -Property @{Name="Resolved Tag #";Expression={$_.CSName}} -AutoSize;
```

I am trying to get it to look like below

```
Tag # Entered        Resolved Tag #
-------------        --------------
c63001               C63001
```

.

.

.

EDIT for more help:

```
$OSInfo `
    | Format-Table -Property `
        @{ Name = "Tag # Entered"; Expression = { $tag1 }; Width = 10 }, `
        @{ Name = "Resolved Tag #"; Expression = { $_.CSName } };
```

.

.

Also trying to get these two things on the same line but it isn't working:

```
$domain = Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -Computer $tag1 | Format-Table -Property @{Name="Username";Expression={$_.username}} -Autosize;
$username = (Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -Computer $tag1).UserName.Split("\")[1];
$longname = ((net user $username /domain | Select-String "Full Name") -replace "Full Name","").Trim();
```

I was trying to do it using this:

```
$Test `
    | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property `
        @{ Name = "Tag # Entered";  Expression = { $domain } }, `
        @{ Name = "Resolved Tag #"; Expression = { $longname } };
```

Comment: You'll have to post the output of your first edit and what's not right about it because when I had tried the same thing it worked fine.  Your assignment of `$username` looks correct, though I'm not on a domain computer right now to test the `net user` command, too.  Still, your invocation of `Format-Table` looks correct.  I'm assuming you've set a value for `$domain` elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Woops sorry! used the wrong line of code there. I edited the OP. I am not sure why it doesn't work the way I want to output it... Am I okay with using $Test as the variable? I mean...if I just "echo $domain" and "echo $longname" ..they output fine..but are on different lines. I was putting them the way posted above because I want them on the same line.

Comment: Just to throw the idea out there, if all you're after is printing multiple variables on the same line but not necessarily in tabular format, you can use `Write-Host` with the `-NoNewLine` parameter and handle all the alignment yourself.  Example: `Write-Host -NoNewline "Tag # Entered: $tag1; "; Write-Host "Resolved Tag #: $($OSInfo.CSName)";`  Of course, for that example, you can combine both commands into a single call to `Write-Host` with the `-NoNewline` parameter omitted, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: The way you have it doesn't seem to work...I'm trying to figure out how to write it but just letting you know. All I want to do is put two outputs on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wanted:

```
$CompInfo `
    | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property `
        @{ Name = "Domain\user";  Expression = { $CompInfo.username } }, `
        @{ Name = "Full Name"; Expression = { $fullname } };
```

The reason it didn't work was because I was using $OSInfo which is the win32_operatingsystem class.

```
$OSInfo = get-wmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem -computername $tag1;
$CompInfo = get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem -Computer $tag1;
```

The Domain I was trying to output is pulled with the win32_computersystem class and I was trying to do it under win32_operatingsystem.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the desired output (reformatted whitespace for readability):

```
$OSInfo `
    | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property `
        @{ Name = "Tag # Entered";  Expression = { $tag1 } }, `
        @{ Name = "Resolved Tag #"; Expression = { $_.CSName } };
```

Note that if `$OSInfo` contains multiple items the value of the first column will be the same for all of them (`"c63001"`).

Comment: Works! Is there a way to add more space between them or is that not possible?

Comment: Remember that the output consists of objects. When you have objects, the actual appearance of how PowerShell outputs the objects is of minor importance (the data is all there; the spacing really isn't important).

Comment: @Aaron You can add a `Width` item to the `Hashtable` defining each column (e.g. `@{ Name = "Tag # Entered";  Expression = { $tag1 }; Width = 10 }`).  See the `-Property` parameter of [`Format-Table`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849892.aspx).

Comment: Hmm I tried that but it didnt do anything but also didn't get any errors.

Comment: @Aaron Make sure you remove the `-AutoSize` parameter because that will likely override the `Width` values.

Comment: @{ Name = "Tag # Entered";  Expression = { $tag1 }; Width = 90 }

Still doesn't work :(

Comment: @Aaron That part is correct, but I just tested it and confirmed that you do need to remove the `-AutoSize` parameter passed to the `Format-Table` cmdlet otherwise it will ignore the `Width` values for each property.

Comment: I edited my original post with what I am using. Tell me if I have it correct? I don't notice any width changes. I also added something else that I need help getting on two lines. I tried using the same way as the first question but it doesn't show anything when I run it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43793/discussion-between-aaron-and-bacon)